# grails 2.2.1 not reloading classes

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-2.0

I can't seem to get any grails projects reload ANY classes in development mode.
Running 2.2.1 on Windows7 ,  using IntelliJ 11.1.4 , and 12.1

Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: You need a fresh IDEA version for proper Grails 2.2 support.

Comment: Upgraded IDEA to latest ... but no luck with reloading

Comment: This is clearly related to the grails maven plugin using the wrong springloaded dependency

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue with IntelliJ 12.02 and Grails 2.1.3. The fix that i have found has been written down in this post.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98131

A new version of IntelliJ also saved my issues with broken auto reload.

Comment: Thanks Marko, sounds like upgrading intelliJ should help. Will try and report back.

Comment: Just upgraded IntellJ to 12.1 still no luck. A very basic auto gen app  shows Reload:False (see picture above)